# fill Content(html) in div for fix height and widhth using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting long text using ajax in json form I want to  fill those content in the fix height div

suppose I have div  height 500px and width 300px. and font size is 16px

i want any javascript recursive method  that can fill data according to height and width of div and can return me remaining text.

if any one can do that  then Please provide  me solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is possible to do mathematically if you use a monospaced font (i.e., you know the height/width of each character and the height/width of the div, so it's simple division to know how many characters will fit).  If your font isn't fixed-width, you might be able to use a jQuery plugin to test the height of each line and stop when lines are lower than the bottom of the div.

Comment: Add the content into the div character by character until its height exceeds _y_. Stop and return the remaining characters.

Comment: Why don't just put all in the div and in the div you set overflow="hidden"

Comment: I have a huge text If I am doing it character by character then its becomes very slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't just put all in the div and in the div you set 
   overflow="hidden"

Create a temp div, fix it width and append text until it exceed your height then stop, after that copy all content to the main div

```
var s = 'Your long long long long long long long long long long content';
var i = 0;
var tmpdiv = $('<div style="width:50px; height:auto; position:absolute; left:-99999px"/>').appendTo(document.body);
while (i < s.length-1 && tmpdiv.height() < 50){
  tmpdiv.append(s[i]);
  i++;
}

$('#fixdiv').html(tmpdiv.html());
```

Comment: I put -1 when I made my comment about your remark, but I removed it when you edited the post. Another user may still have to do so.

Comment: I have implemented this code  it is creating me 500 page of book but I have a huge data so that it is taking too much processing time. can't any method will create page(div) very fast

Answer (score 1):

First of all, wrap the text inside a `<span>` in put it in your `<div>`. I'm assuming that `div` is your fixed size element here:

```
// Be careful about text nodes, or use firstElementChild instead
var span = div.firstChild, text = span.innerText, rest = "";
if (span.offsetHeight > 500) {
    var totalLength = 0, markLength, i = 0,
        rects = span.getClientRects();
    for (; i < rects.length; i++) {
        totalLength += rects[i].right - rects[i].left;
        if (rects[i].bottom - rects[0].top <= 500)
            markLength = totalLength;
    }
    var mark = Math.floor(text.length * markLength / totalLength);
    span.textContent = text.substring(0, mark);
    rest = text.substring(mark);
}
```

The variable `rest` contains the remaining part.
Beware that this method uses some approximations, and sometimes may not fill the container to the brim. In some unlucky cases, it may even overflow the container, so you have to run it again until you get the correct size.